# Find if executable is available in PATH

Tags: windows, vbscript, path

I need to know if an executable is available in PATH from a vbscript.
In *nix I would use 'which' command to to that.
What do I use in vbscript?
Solution needs to be compatible with WinXP so 'where' command is not for me.

Comment: I know it's tangential, but what do you plan to do if it *isn't*? And how do you know if you've located the "right" executable?

Comment: You're relying on only one possible executable with a given name?

Comment: But what if something else in the path has the same exe name?

Comment: Good point. IDK. But I think that the chances of that are low so will fix it as documented :)

Comment: I'm trying to point you towards: if you need to execute a specific binary, you need an explicit path to it (or a defined method for finding such). `PATH` is a convenience for users, not a facility for finding specific binaries.

Comment: Well, I would use `which` too, from `gnuwin32`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But doesn't the fact that the PATH is divided into USER and SYSTEM in Windows mean that the latter one is not just a convenience for users but rather a method for system to find binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
On Error Resume Next
wshshell.run "your_exec", 6, True
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WshShell.Popup(Err.Number)
    ' Handle error
    Err.Clear
End If
On Error Goto 0
set wshshell = nothing
```

The `your_exec` must be a call to the executable made in such a way that would return immediately, which could be a problem if that executable doesn't provide some command line option to do so. In my case I'm just calling the executable to show its version: `my.exe -version`.